# Make android application using fragments to run on Android 2.X

Tags: android, user-interface

this is my sittuation ...
A customer gave me an application done partially by somebody else. That person used fragments to build the UI.

The guy who gave me the application to finish the development of it, just realized that he wanted that the application run on android devices with 2.X

So, I am wondering if it is possible to have two UI's : One for Android devices that support fragments, and another one for android devices which do not support fragments.

In case that is possible, can that be deffined on the xml as alternate resources is done ? Or that needs to be programatically? (I mean check android os version and alternate UI's)

Thanks!

Comment: Use the android.support.v4.app.Fragment in the support library.

Answer (score 3):

Lucky for you, the Support Library has `Fragment`s in it, and supports back to Android 1.6. So you can use the "support" class for `Fragment`s and it will work on old and new devices alike.

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now, my problem is that the application is using SherlockBar :S And, I see that I would need to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; Is it possible to use the Support Library and at the same time use the SherlockBar ?

Comment: You can use SherlockFragmentActivity and SherlockFragment that are actually using the support library ;)
[source](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html)